# Escaped quotations in angular ui ui grid when using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, angular-ui-grid

update 2: I haven't been able to duplicate this issue in a plunker, so this question is about something between the lines that could be causing this issue, rather than how to fix the issue.

I tried to duplicate this issue with a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8Fb7o8OjUFdXOLKAaS7?p=preview) but the issue didn't show in a simple ng-repeat. This tells me the issue is within ui-grid itself. The issue is that I've got rows in my grid which have escaped quotations, because people like to name their companys "Anna's Company", and I'm displaying information about these customers but seeing the escape characters. (I'm seeing "Anna\'s Company")

Do I need to create a custom cell template? I don't know what's causing the escape characters to be visible, so I don't know what that template should look like. For example, in my contrived plunkr above, I've got this in the controller:

```
$scope.list = [
  {name: "Bob Saget"},
  {name: "Aardvark\'s Name"},
  {name: 'Everyone\'s Name'},
  {name: 'Escaped \'Quotations\''}
];
```

and this in the html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="names in list">{{names.name}}</li>
</body>
```

The escape characters are not visible. I found the [default templates for ui-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating) via google. This is the default template for the cell, what changes do I have to make? Apply a filter?

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</span></div>
```

Update: **[Here is plunkr with issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/AbFbxHCKkAekwezIAOca?p=preview)**. My question is then why is it behaving differently when the data is being returned from JSON/AJAX (my real situation) different from the contrived examples I've produced

Comment: you can reproduce it using json file.

Comment: @pankajparkar the plunkr you edited into my question doesn't load anything into the grid

Comment: beacuse the '(quote) is causing issue

Comment: Even without `\'` and just `'` its not loading the json

Comment: even without any quotations in the string at all it's not displaying the json

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/AbFbxHCKkAekwezIAOca?p=preview check this..if you add ' it won't work.

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using, I opened that plunkr on chrome, firefox, and even IE, and that is definitely also not working initially, not even loading headers. As you shared it, nothing is loaded in the preview.

Comment: ended up solving this by removing the escape characters on the server side in php with `stripslashes($results[$i][$ii])`